# Error with the people picker when trying to assign permissions to Business Data Connectivity Service

Tags: forms-authentication, people-picker

I am getting this error in the event log when trying the above.

An exception occurred in AllUsers claim provider when calling SPClaimProvider.FillResolve(): The entry 'FBAdb' has already been added. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\47514\web.config line 1170).

We are using FBA for a number of applications. When the connection string is removed the people picker works but FBA does not. There is no additional entries in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

You can try checking Alternate Access Mappings of the site you are experiencing problems with in central administration